# How can I check for a duplicate object in SQLite table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating an application in Xamarin.Forms - it is an event management application - in the application the user can sign up to events and create events. When you create an event - you are given a code for that event. There is a window in which you can input the code and then it registers you to that event. So for example if someone wants to check who is coming to a birthday party they could put the code on the invitation and the people who receive the invitation could open the app - input the code - and say whether they are going or not and add some messages.

I followed this tutorial to implement SQLite into Xamarin.Forms:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Here is the code:

```
    public class LocalEventDatabase : ILocalEventDatabase
    {
        static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> lazyInitializer = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() =>
        {
            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        });

        static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database => lazyInitializer.Value;
        static bool initialized = false;

        public LocalEventDatabase()
        {
            InitializeAsync().SafeFireAndForget(false, new Action<Exception>(async(Exception ex) => 
            {
                await Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(string.Format($"Don't panic! An exception has occurred: {ex.Message}"), "An exception has occurred", "OK");
            }));
        }

        async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(Event).Name))
                {
                    await Database.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(Event)).ConfigureAwait(false); // not entirely understood what configure await is?
                }
                initialized = true;
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Event>> GetRegisteredEventsAsync()
        {
            return await Database.Table<Event>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Event> GetEventAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return await Database.Table<Event>().Where(i => i.EventGuid == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<int> InsertEventAsync(Event @event)
        {
            return await Database.InsertAsync(@event);
        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteEventAsync(Event @event)
        {
            return await Database.DeleteAsync(@event);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code behind for searching through the codes:

```
public class FindEventViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Event> _results;
        private ObservableCollection<Event> _events;

        public ICommand SearchCommand => new Command(OnSearchCommand);

        public string EntryText { get; set; }

        // FAB stands = 'floating action button'
        public ObservableCollection<Event> Results
        {
            get => _results;
            set
            {
                _results = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Results));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Event> Events
        {
            get => _events;
            set
            {
                _events = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Events));
            }
        }

        public FindEventViewModel(IDialogService dialogService,
                                  IEventService eventService,
                                  IShellNavigationService shellNavigationService,
                                  IThemeService themeService,
                                  ILocalEventDatabase localEventDatabase) : base(dialogService, eventService, shellNavigationService, themeService, localEventDatabase)
        {

        }
        public async Task<FindEventViewModel> OnAppearing()
        {
            await LoadData();
            return this;
        }

        private async Task LoadData()
        {
            var data = await _eventService.GetAllEventsAsync();
            Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>(data);
            Results = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
        }

        public async void OnSearchCommand()
        {
            if (SearchEvents(EntryText).SearchResult == SearchResult.Match)
            {
                _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format($"Found matching event"), Color.Green, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                var eventFound = SearchEvents(EntryText).EventFound;
                Results.Add(eventFound);

                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(eventFound));

                // may be unneccessary to use it directly rather than with DI but in this case it is needed in order to evaluate what the user has pressed
                var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new Acr.UserDialogs.ConfirmConfig()
                {
                    Title = "Sign up?",
                    Message = string.Format($"Would you like to sign up to {eventFound.EventTitle}?"),
                    OkText = "Yes",
                    CancelText = "No",
                });

                if (result)
                {
                    await _localEventDatabase.InsertEventAsync(eventFound);

                    _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format($"You signed up to {eventFound.EventTitle} successfully"), Color.CornflowerBlue, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    MessagingCenter.Send(eventFound as Event, MessagingCenterMessages.EVENT_SIGNEDUP);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format($"No event found matching query - retry?"), Color.Red, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            }
        }

        public EventSearchResult SearchEvents(string code)
        {
            foreach (Event _event in Events)
            {
                if (_event.EventCode == code)
                {
                    return new EventSearchResult()
                    {
                        SearchResult = SearchResult.Match,
                        EventFound = _event,
                    };
                }
            }

            return new EventSearchResult()
            {
                SearchResult = SearchResult.NoMatch,
            };
        }
    }
```

The method returns a search result and the event found. One problem - the user can sign up to the same event twice. In the tutorial I followed it doesn't mention how to check for any duplicate items in the database table?

Comment: You query the DB for whatever fields would constitute a "duplicate" for your use case.  If the query returns any rows, then it already exists.

Comment: @TommyReborn About query duplicate item in table, you can use `SELECT name, section FROM tbl GROUP BY name, section HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT thank you could you also help me with my other question if that's ok?

Comment: @TommyReborn About other question, you can provide other thread to get help.